# how to find end of slide height and last added element position

Tags: java, powerpoint, docx4j

I am exploring pptx4j to generate slide compatible to office 2013. One of the requirement is to move the element(new row of table/ text box/ new table/ any other element) to next slide when the element added goes beyond the slide height.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write you own logic to calculate the height of your content, but there is nothing at present in pptx4j which does this for you, I'm afraid.